# Angular : How to pass data from parent component to child component?

Tags: angular

How to filter list when the input is given in parent component?

I am able to filter when the list and the search box is in the same component but failing when they are in different components. I tried using @Intput which did not work.

my code:

**parent.html**

```html
<div style="height:10%;">
   <input type="text" placeholder="search here.." class="search_box" [(ngModel)]="term">
<app-environment [term]="term"></app-environment>
 </div>
```

**child.html**

```html
   <tr *ngFor="let environ of environmentLists | filter:term; let i = index">
            <td>{{environ.rgn}}</td>
            <td ng-maxlength="5">{{environ.serverType}}</td>
            <td>{{environ.hostName}}</td>
            <td>{{environ.createDate}}</td>
        </tr>
```

**child.js**

```java-script
@Component({
  selector: 'app-environment',
  templateUrl: './environment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./environment.component.css'],
  providers: [DashboardService]
})
export class EnvironmentComponent implements OnInit {

  environmentLists: String[];
 @Input() term: string;

  constructor(private _dashboardService: DashboardService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._dashboardService.getEnvironments()
      .subscribe((environmentData) => this.environmentLists = environmentData);
  }



}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO,  [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: if you create a minimal example on stackblitz, you'll get help quickly... else you can share the error you see in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may consider a simplest way  just create a method related to filter and call this method from parent everytime the model change

*parent*

```
<input [(ngModel)]="term"  (ngModelChange)="child.filter(term)">
<app-child #child></app-child>
```

child

```
  public filter(term: string = "") {
    term = term.trim(); // remove empty space 
    if (term) { // if the user send an empty string like spaces
      this.filterd = this.list.filter((v: string) => v.includes(term));
    } else { // reset 
      this.filterd = this.list;
    }
  }
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53702604)

Comment: I am facing an below error                                                                                                   AppComponent.html:17 ERROR TypeError: environment.includes is not a function
    at environment.component.ts:38
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at EnvironmentComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/environment/environment.component.ts.EnvironmentComponent.filter (environment.component.ts:38)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AppComponent.html:17)
    at handleEvent (core.es5.js:11998)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13467)

Comment: insted of  v.includes(term) you can use  `v.indexOf(term) != -1`

Comment: is it possible to share with us your filter method ?

Comment: yes tried both. its giving the same error.  please find the below code                                     public filter(term: string = "") {
  
    term = term.trim(); // remove empty space 
    if (term) { // if the user send an empty string like spaces
      this.environmentListsFiltered = this.environmentLists.filter((environment:string ) => environment.includes(term));
    } else { // reset 
      this.environmentListsFiltered= this.environmentLists;
    }
    console.log(this.environmentLists);
  }

Comment: is `environmentLists` has just list of string ? and try this  `(environment || '').includes(term)); `

Comment: working now. forgot to convert the enviroment to string as environmentList has objects. Thanks for the help

Comment: can you please suggest what can be done If I want to filter the on multiple child with same parent term. My requirement is like, I have a search box in appComponent which is a parent, when the user enters anything in search box it should be filtered in multiple child components. one problem Iam facing right now is, the child component's html is getting displayed on the parent when I create a reference in parent component like   <input type="text" placeholder="search here.." class="search_box" [(ngModel)]="term" (ngModelChange)="child.filter(term)"/>
<app-environment #child></app-environment>

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your `filter` pipe is implemented and available in the child component. Note: this will re-filter the list on every view update and is possibly inefficient.
e.g.

```
@Pipe({name: 'filter'})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(values: string[], term: string): number {
    return values.filter(value => value.indexOf(term) > -1);
  }
}
```

It would be better to filter your list only when the search term changes, e.g.

```
export class EnvironmentComponent implements OnInit {

  environmentLists: String[];
  environmentListsFiltered: String[];
  @Input() set term(term: string) {
    this._term = term;
    this.environmentListsFiltered = environmentLists.filter(item => item.indexOf(term)>-1);
  }
  get term(): string {
    return this._term;
  };
  private _term: string;
}
```

and use it in the template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let environ of environmentListsFiltered; let i = index">
```

You can also use observables for better change management, see e.g. https://stackblitz.com/github/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search-example